# VBA: Dynamic arrays when you meet certain criteria

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my problem.

I have data like this in my excel

```
Manufactuer     Model Capacity

x                   1000                    
x                   3000   
y                   1800                 
y                   4000 
z                   1300
```

I want to loop through these data and when the manufactuer is the same I want to get the minimum capacity and copy it to another sheet. The problem is that I don't know the exact amount of the models of each manufactuer. For example, one time the X manufactuer can be found 5 times and another time can be found 4.

Comment: What's wrong with MINIFS or even a pseudo-MINIF?

Comment: You could use a pivot table, or Power Query.

Answer (score 3):

If your `Manufacturer` column is `A:A` and your `Model Capacity` column is `B:B` then the formula

`{=MIN(IF(A:A="y";B:B))}`

will give you the minimum value of `y` Manufacturer (1800).

Change the letter `y` to change Manufacturer and press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` to place the braces.

Answer (score 1):

Try this after modifying to suit your own ranges and worksheet names.

```
sub minCapacities()

    dim i as long, arr as variant, dict as object

    set dict = createobject("scripting.dictionary")
    dict.comparemode = vbtextcompare

    with worksheets("sheet1")
        arr = .range(.cells(2, "A"), .cells(.rows.count, "B").end(xlup)).value2
    end with

    for i=lbound(arr, 1) to ubound(arr, 1)
        if dict.exists(arr(i, 1)) then
            dict.item(arr(i, 1)) = application.min(dict.item(arr(i, 1)), arr(i, 2))
        else
            dict.item(arr(i, 1)) = arr(i, 2)
        end if
    next i

    with worksheets("sheet2")
        .cells(1, "A").resize(1, 2) = array("Manufactuer", "Min Capacity")
        .cells(2, "A").resize(dict.count, 1) = application.transpose(dict.keys)
        .cells(2, "B").resize(dict.count, 1) = application.transpose(dict.items)
    end with

end sub
```